# Kodi - Play Music and Minimize

Tags: kodi

I want Kodi to play music (YouTube) in the background, without it displaying anything on the screen - freeing up the machine to display pictures, etc.
Per [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27414/minimize-kodi-to-run-full-screen-x-on-osmc-alpha-4#) minimizing isn't possible - but is there some command/API to completely turn off the display?
P.S. It's running on a Raspberry Pi 2.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing the `\` on the keyboard should bring standard window borders and buttons. Then you can minimize the window.

Im pretty sure it should work, but I can't confirm it on Raspbian at the current time. Try it!